# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Json error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
        for i in os.listdir("./saves/"):
            path = './saves/' + i
            if path.endswith(".json"):
                with open(path, "r"):
                    config = json.loads(path)
                    ctime = config["Creation Time"]
```

Okay, this is the small code that's causing errors. I'm getting a json decoder error Here is the callback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/acrobat/PycharmProjects/Jan9coderun/TranslatorVCS/Quiz.py", line 318, in saveGame
    config = json.loads(path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My saves folder is in the same working directory as my code and has one `quiz.json`, one `notes.txt`, and one `__init__.py` file.

Comment: What does the json file look like?

Comment: This could be caused by an invalid or empty JSON file.

Comment: Oh. You probably want `with open(path) as f: config = json.load(f)`

Comment: The file was invalid, I see that now. That also resolves the error in my next comment. It seems to be making bad json files I might post another question for that

Comment: I did what juanpa said, and I got a different error, Extra date: (lines and columns)